# как получить треугольную часть Bitmap

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

Для приложения на Android требуется получить из имеющегося bitmap его половину, обрезанную по диагонали (т.е. треугольную часть). Насколько знаю, `createBitmap()` можно получить только прямоугольную часть bitmap'а. Понимаю, что нужны какие-то преобразования. Подскажите какие? Или свой вариант решения?

Comment: Битмапы треугольные не бывают. Что будет во второй половине? Залито черным\белым\прозрачным?

Comment: Ок понял, во второй части будет тот же  bitmap повернутый на 90. Скоректирую вопрос как- как наложить друг на друга два bitmap, чтобы получить одну картинку из двух разделенных по диагонали?

Comment: Не с мог с телефона найти картинку но в целом нужно добиться похожего эффекта https://goo.gl/images/G92pzk

Answer (score 1):

Берете битмап с альфа-каналом, проходите нужные пиксели, делая их прозрачными.
Делаете копию результата и ее поворачиваете на 180.
Рисуете один поверх другого.
Готово.